# MacOS man utility seems to be broken

Tags: macos, command, manpage

My "man" utility on MacOS Ventura 13.1 seems to be broken. When I try running "man ls" from the command line I get:

```
/usr/bin/man: eval: line 413: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/usr/bin/man: eval: line 414: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I expected to see the man page for "ls" displayed in the terminal. Any ideas how to fix this (short of editing /usr/bin/man itself)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops...please ignore. I found the issue. I had an old setup for MANPAGER that integrates with the "bat" utility for displaying man pages that was the culprit.